# About UIAlertView with Textfield...

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this code to prompt the `UIAlertView`, with `UITextfield`:

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"New List Item", @"new_list_dialog")
                                                      message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

But I would like to add a get the textfield value, after the user click "OK", and after the user click , I want to call a method, how can I assign that to the myAlertView? Thank you.

Comment: Just bear in mind this is not officially supported by the SDK and is liable to break any time Apple changes the UIAlertView implementation. And this isn't as unlikely as you think, all those hacked decimal keys on the numeric keypad broke on iOS 4, so this stuff does happen.

Comment: but is there any "official" way to do so?

Comment: @DNB5brims I see that you are an active SO user and this is a highly viewed question (45k views in a year). Could you consider changing the accepted answer to the *official* way of doing so as answered by "Hamed Rajabi" below. UIAlertView now has a built in property of `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`

Comment: Just used the accepted solution painstakingly and with error, only to come back and see the second answer in this thread is an official documented way of doing this. Then came to this comment section urge you to update the selected answer to the official solution and save others lots of wasted time I just experienced, and I see that I already asked you to do so over 3 years ago. Shame that still hasn't changed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Declare the text field as global.And in the method of alertView clicked `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` just take the value of the textfield and do the operations you want with it.....

Heres the revised code

```
UITextField *myTextField;
...
{

UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"New List Item", @"new_list_dialog")
                                                      message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
}
....
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSLog(@"string entered=%@",myTextField.text);
}
```

For iOS 5 and later
You can use `alertViewStyle` property of `UIAlertView`.

Please refer Hamed's Answer for the same

Comment: this is a very lazy answer.  perhaps you should fully ANSWER the question

Comment: default property is there to show alert with textField then why create textField programatically..

Comment: @Gamechanger This is a 5 year old thread and also it is mentioned in the answer already that **For iOS 5 and later You can use alertViewStyle property of UIAlertView**

Answer (score 202):

If you want to add a TextField to an UIAlertView, you can use this property (alertViewStyle) for UIAlertView:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                message:@"Message"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

and in .h file of it add UIAlertViewDelegate as a protocol and implement the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex delegate method in the .m file:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"%@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);
}
```

I hope, it works for you!

**Note: "Available in iOS 5.0 and later"**

Comment: Are you sure that is good for the AppStore submissions?..i remember that textFieldAtIndex is a private method..time ago apple rejects me an app for this method...or maybe in iOS 5 is different(?)

Comment: I saw [http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html). On this page wrote  "Available in iOS 5.0 and later".

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated since iOS 9.0

Answer (score 21):

As of iOS 8 `UIAlertView` has been deprecated in favor of [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/), which adds support for adding `UITextField`s.

#### Swift

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title",
                              message: nil,
                              preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addTextField { (textField) in
    // optionally configure the text field
    textField.keyboardType = .alphabet
}

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [unowned alert] (action) in
    if let textField = alert.textFields?.first {
        print(textField.text ?? "Nothing entered")
    }
}
alert.addAction(okAction)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

#### Objective-C

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                               message:nil
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    // optionally configure the text field
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
}];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                         UITextField *textField = [alert.textFields firstObject];
                                                 }];
[alert addAction:okAction];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: But in Objective-C code, there is a retain cycle: alert owns action, action owns handler block, which owns alert...

Comment: @RadekWilczak Nice catch! Declare `__weak UITextField *weakTextField = [alertController textFields][0];` outside the action, and then inside the action block use `weakTextField.text`

Answer (score 2):

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a global variable for the UITextfield, you want to retrieve value in your AlertView Delegate method.I have created a post in my blog on the topic "How to add UITextField to UIAlertView from XIB". You can take a look at the following link.

http://creiapp.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-add-uitextfield-to-uialertview.html

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hey Welcome"

message:@"MSG" 

delegate:self

cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok Ji" 

otherButtonTitles:nil];

UITextField textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, 70.0, 200.0, 25.0)];

[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[alert addSubview:textField];

[alert show];
[alert release];
```